# Using Razor Pages coredotnet how can I load a partial view via ajax

Tags: ajax, partial-views, razor-pages

In using Razor pages, it is simple to use partial using `@Html.Partial(..)`. 
 However, when a drop down changes, I want to refresh part of the view - the part rendered by the partial view.

I have searched lots, and found answers such as: https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/2073 where they say partials are meant for code behind.

Is there a reasonable workaround such that I can re-render a subset of the view which is defined in a partial view? What is the best practice way of achieving this?

Comment: are u using some library? such as jquery or angular? it is possible to setup something like a tag helper. i have done this with angular before

Comment: No, learning pure razor pages in dotnet core v2.1

Comment: well ajax is a js concept (client + server) which is no longer pure razor (serverside) I have looked for something built into razor to via js, but never found anything. So if you need to re-render, you will have to use js in some form.

Comment: on what events do you need the view re-rendered? do you have any use cases?

Comment: I think the scenario is a simple one. I have a drop down, with a list of departments. When the drop down changes, I want to load a new set of modules which relate to the new department. I could reload the whole page and use the same logic as when it was first renderd, but just replacing the section in question seems better

Comment: Detecting the dropdown would be a dom event which would easily become js. If you are looking for something built-in/first party, Microsoft was developing something years back for similar usage. https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive
However, ms no longer provides support for this since everyone is moving towards js libraries for such ajax update functionalities.

Comment: I am very happy to use Ajax/Jquery, that is not the issue, just whether we have to revert to MVC for this partial load rendering, or can continue using Razor Pages and achieve that somehow though this

Comment: regarding using razor, check my comment on Brian's answer. Basically, your view needs to be accessible as a **URL**. This means, you will need to think of replacements in case you are passing your model via `@Html.Partial(...)`. For instance, you can take the ID as a url parameter and fetch the data

Comment: to create a razor page for this, just make a page and ensure you set the layout to null

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

Have an action method that can be called to reload just the partial view:

```
public ActionResult Reload()
{
    return PartialView("NameOfPartialView");
}
```

Get it from the client (I'll use jQuery):

```
$.ajax({ 
  type: "post", 
  url: "Reload",
  data: {},
  success: function(d) {
   //d is the HTML content returned from the Action Method
   $("#parentelementaroundinnerdata").html(d);
  }
});
```

Returning the partial view from the action method returns an HTML string, and that can be injected into the page using a parent element to replace its contents with the update.  That means when rendering the original, have the setup as the following:

```
<div id="parentelementaroundinnerdata">
   @Html.Partial("NameOfPartialView")
</div>
```

You can use the same partial from an AJAX request and for loading an initial result - sometimes you have to be careful within the partial on what is going on because of that though...

Comment: Does this work with Razor Pages? this looks like standard MVC, or does one have to muddy between both?

Comment: this way requires your partial view to be accessible via a URL. the controller shown here just makes sure there is a URL. you can also make a razor view with layout set to null that could act as your partial view

Comment: Well, the AJAX request accesses an action method, whereas Html.Partial doesn't worry about loading anything from an action method.  The only reason it's exposed is because it will reload the partial view, not be executed from the original view execution.  I updated the sample above.  As far as layout, I never specify the layout attribute as null and no layout page ever pops up with the partial declaration.  This is great because you can, in theory, define the same view in both view mode and partial view mode, but that does become tricky.

Comment: So I am still unsure of the MVC vs Razor Pages element in all this. In Razor Pages, it would be public IActionResult OnGetReload() and PartialView is not available as a return type. So presumably need to reference another MVC dll somewhere. So not really getting to the crux of the matter - Razor Pages

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't realize that distinction, but will this solution (at the bottom) work: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6759